# associate a value to the corresponding file

Tags: c, hash

I have a program that generates a hash key from a file. And also verifies if the result hash is equal to the expected hash. But the program is just working for one file each time. Now, I was trying to generate a hash key from each file in a given directory and do the comparison with each expected hash.

For that I have the code below to read the directory. But I am not having success to associate  the expected hash to each file that I have in the directory.

With `strcmp` I can compare and it is already working, but then how can I associate the correct expected hash with the corresponding file? Do you know how to do that?

```
PCSTR text = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\txt_1.txt";
PCSTR pptx = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\Test.pptx";

DIR           *d;
d = opendir("C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\");
struct dirent *dir;

char name[256][256];
int count = 0;
int index = 0;

char TextExpected[] = "811676652bf08c0a91a849d66bb2a46c";
char PptxExpected[] = "b011367338c3264f1f3f74107060d788";

while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);


        strcpy(name[count],dir->d_name);

        count++;


        if(strcmp(dir->d_name,"test.pptx") == 0){
            // how can I do here to associate the hashExpected to the file "test.pptx"
        }
        if(strcmp(dir->d_name,"test.txt") == 0){
            // how can I do here to associate the hashExpected to the file "test.txt"
        }

    }
    closedir(d);

    while( count > 0 )
    {
    ...
```

Inside the while ( count > 0) I execute the code to generate the hash key for each file in the directory(count > 0).

This is the **complete program**, it is working just that associating part I am not having success in getting it to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16


int main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    PCSTR text = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\txt_1.txt";
    PCSTR pptx = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\Test.pptx";




    DIR           *d;
    d = opendir("C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\");
    struct dirent *dir;
    struct dirent *test;
    char name[256][256];
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;

    int expected[25];
    int countcount;

    char testtest[256][256];

    char TextExpected[] = "811676652bf08c0a91a849d66bb2a46c";
    char PptxExpected[] = "b011367338c3264f1f3f74107060d788";



    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);


        strcpy(name[count],dir->d_name);

        count++;


        if(strcmp(dir->d_name,"test.pptx") == 0){
            // how can I do here to associate the hashExpected to the file "test.pptx"
        }
        if(strcmp(dir->d_name,"test.txt") == 0){
            // how can I do here to associate the hashExpected to the file "test.txt"
        }

    }
    closedir(d);

    while( count > 0 )
    {

        bool incorrect = FALSE;

        char hashResult[MD5LEN * 2 + 1] = "";
        hFile = CreateFile(text, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

        if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        {
            incorrect = TRUE;
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", text, dwStatus);
            return (int)dwStatus;
        }

        // Get handle to the crypto provider
        if(!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return (int)dwStatus;
        }

        if(!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            return (int)dwStatus;
        }

        while(ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL))
        {
            if(0 == cbRead)
                break;

            if(!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
            {
                dwStatus = GetLastError();
                printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
                CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                return (int)dwStatus;
            }
        }

        cbHash = MD5LEN;

        if(CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
        {
            DWORD i;

            printf("MD5 expected, versus MD5 of file %s is:\n", text);
            printf("%s\n", TextExpected);
            for(i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
            {
                printf("%c%c",
                       rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                       rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
                hashResult[i * 2] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
                hashResult[i * 2 + 1] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
            }
            printf("\n");

            if(_strcmpi(hashResult, TextExpected) == 0)
                printf("Hash is the same\n");
            else
                printf("Hash is different\n");
        }
        else
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        }

        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        return (int)dwStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*icual*"? I knew I recognized that code from somewhere. (It's spelled "equal".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strcpy(name[count],dir->d_name);
```

`d_name` is relative filename, for example `"test.txt"`, but most likely you want to use full path name for crypt functions. Use full path instead. Example:

```
strcpy(name[count],"c:\\dir\\");
strcat(name[count],dir->d_name);
```

`readdir`'s result includes `"."` and `".."` which are basically useless, you want to skip them:

```
if(strcmp(dir->d_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name,"..") == 0)
    continue;
```

`while( count > 0 )` puts the code in infinite loop. You mean to do this instead:

```
int index = 0;
while( index < count )
{
    const char* filename = name[index];
    index++;
}
```

Note, you want to use `name[index]` and not `name`. You probably don't want to exit the loop whenever error occurs, instead you want to continue.

Finally, add a function which will look up the expect hash value for known files. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

const char* get_expected_hash(const char* filename)
{
    PCSTR text = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\txt_1.txt";
    PCSTR pptx = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\Test.pptx";

    const char* TextExpected = "811676652bf08c0a91a849d66bb2a46c";
    const char* PptxExpected = "b011367338c3264f1f3f74107060d788";

    if (stricmp(filename, text) == 0)
        return TextExpected;

    if (stricmp(filename, pptx) == 0)
        return PptxExpected;

    return "unknown hash";
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    //const char* dirname = "C:\\Users\\Jax\\Desktop\\files\\files2\\";
    const char* dirname = "c:\\test\\";

    DIR  *d;
    d = opendir(dirname);
    struct dirent *dir;
    char files[256][256];
    int count = 0;

    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(dir->d_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name,"..") == 0)
            continue;

        strcpy(files[count],dirname);
        strcat(files[count],dir->d_name);
        count++;
    }
    closedir(d);

    // Get handle to the crypto provider
    if(!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", (int)dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return (int)dwStatus;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while( index < count )
    {
        const char* filename = files[index];
        index++;

        printf("%s\n", filename);

        char hashResult[MD5LEN * 2 + 1] = "";
        hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

        if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        {
            //incorrect = TRUE;
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", filename, (int)dwStatus);
            return (int)dwStatus;
        }

        if(!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", (int)dwStatus);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            continue;
        }

        while(ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL))
        {
            if(0 == cbRead)
                break;

            if(!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
            {
                dwStatus = GetLastError();
                printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", (int)dwStatus);
                CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                continue;
            }
        }

        cbHash = MD5LEN;

        if(CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
        {
            DWORD i;

            printf("MD5 expected, versus MD5 of file %s is:\n", filename);

            const char* TextExpected = get_expected_hash(filename);
            printf("%s\n", TextExpected);

            for(i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
            {
                printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4], rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
                hashResult[i * 2] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
                hashResult[i * 2 + 1] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];
            }
            //printf("\n");

            if(_strcmpi(hashResult, TextExpected) == 0)
                printf("Hash is the same\n");
            else
                printf("Hash is different\n");
        }
        else
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", (int)dwStatus);
            continue;
        }

        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

    return 0;
}
```